# Xamarin.Forms SetHasNavigationBar false causes jump on PushAsync

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am adding a navigation bar using

`MainPage = new NavigationPage (new Home ());`

Then on my `Home.cs` page I do not want to show the navigation bar, it is only for pages that link from this page I want to show the navigation bar. To stop the navigation bar from showing on this page I using the following code at the start of `Home.cs`.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, false);
```

From here when using `Navigation.Push.Async` to go to another page I get a "jump" (movement?) at the bottom of `Home.cs`. Its like it adds on the height for the navigation bar on the next page.

On iOS it causes the obvious jump if you set the background color on `Home.cs` to anything but white.

On Android it seems to only cause this "jump" when navigating back to the `Home.cs` page.

This is the code I am using to push to the next page.

```
btn.Clicked += async (sender, e) => await Navigation.PushAsync (new TestPage ());
```

I have tried to remove all padding.margins from the pages but this has not helped. As I started a new project to test this there isn't anything else for me to change so I cannot think of any other changes that would solve this.

Gif below:
[Tried to show the jump in this gif](http://recordit.co/lNthPGKlJL)

**Note:** *Keep an eye on the `Home.cs` (Grey) page.*

Comment: I'm also facing same issue.. How to slove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of looking around I have found this to be a bug in Xmarin.Forms. No news on when there will be a fix or any work around.

Please keep an eye on the bug report here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32830

---

### Work Around (ish?)

As a workaround I have stopped the animation from happening at all. Adding `false` as a second parameter will disable the animation. This doesnt look great but maybe better then seeing the little "jump" problem.

```
btn.Clicked += async (sender, e) => await Navigation.PushAsync (new TestPage (), false);
```

Comment: that sucks. It tooks so long time but never fixed.

Answer (score 6):

**Alternative work around**

I my situation I came from a SpringBoard without a navigationbar. So what I did when going to a ContentPage with navigation bar was to Hide before and Show the navigationbar after the PushAsync.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false);

await Navigation.PushAsync(page);

NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, true);
```

Not sure if this is a neat solution, but at least it gets rid of the jumping effect. As side effect it makes the navigationbar slide in from the top that looks more like a well thought UI animation then jumping content.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, you can use PushModalAsync, if this will suite to your app.

Comment: Well it does stop the problem I was having but for my application I feel it doesn't work very well with it. Was more looking for a workaround to keep the animation as it was but stop the "jump" problem. Thank you for your suggestion tho, may come in handle for someone.